# Amsul Pickadate - Prevent Default Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

New to this, just a quick question. I am using the Amsul Pickadate library to generate a calendar.

My issue is that it's initially setting the hidden field as today's date - however todays date is disabled so I'm not too sure as to what this is being put into the hidden fields value...? Surely a disabled date shouldn't end up becoming the value of the hidden field?!

I would like the hidden fields to just be initially blank until the users selects a date - how can I achieve this?

```js
options = {
  onClose: function() {
    this.$holder.blur();
  },
  today: '',
  clear: '',
  disable: [
    1, 7
  ],
  format: 'd/m/yyyy',
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  hiddenName: true,
  min: +1,
  klass: {
    now: '',
    highlighted: ''
  }
};

//Dates disabled...
disabledDates = [
  new Date(2017, 1, 22)
];

var $arrivalInput = $('.arrival input').pickadate(options);
var $returnInput = $('.return input').pickadate(options);

var arrivalPicker = $arrivalInput.pickadate('picker');
var returnPicker = $returnInput.pickadate('picker');

//Disable any dates...
arrivalPicker.set('disable', disabledDates);
returnPicker.set('disable', disabledDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently came across the same issue, here is the cleanest solution I've came out with:

```js
// set value of hidden input to ''
arrivalPicker._hidden.value = '';
// set state of pickerdate to empty
arrivalPicker.component.item.select = {};
```